# How to avoid horizontal and vertical scroll bars in Flexbox CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I want to create a HTML file that contains an embedded style sheet. The HTML file should show rectangles on the top right corner in a column.

Input

[image]

If the browser window is too small, the rectangles should go into multiple columns and avoid vertical and horizontal scroll bars. My output is coming out like this.

Output

[image]

I have tried my coding this way. But it is not working. Can anybody suggest how to do this?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .col {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  .col {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}

.row {
  float: right;
}

.col {
  margin: 11px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please note that usually media queries should be at the end of the css style, so you avoid overwrite them by mistake (in this case this is why `background-color: olive;` is not working, no matter the window size).

Second of all really the solution really depends a lot on data. Assuming you will always have only 6 boxes and fixed width to the container and to the boxes you can do something like this:

```css
.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  height:500px;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.col {
  margin: 11px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .col {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  .col {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  .row {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Plase note that `height: 500px;` can be modified if you need. Can be even a procent or something else depending on your page structure and your needs. If you need something more generic there isn't a perfect overall solution. But you can try to find a better one depending on your data.